# vb6 Is keeping an old reference locked

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I created a wrapper class to load CLR4(.net) into CLR2(vb6). It works, sort of.

I compile my program in .net(4.0) and run a batch file to create a .tlb. I refrence the .tlb from my vb6 program and everything is awesome.

When I change the wrapper and redo the above process, vb6 will not see the new .tlb, it still uses the old one.

...Anything?

Comment: Try using `CreateObject()` method instead of adding its reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try to un-register the old tlb before deploying the new one. Open a cmd shell and type "regsvr32 /u mytlb.tlb", then deploy the new, and run regsvr32 again without the /u switch.

see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx for additional information.

Comment: I understand that and that is what i thought, however I am not registering the tlb file and cannot unregister the tlb file, because it is not a valid .net assembly is the reason i get

Answer (score 1):

We have a similiar situation here at work ( a vb6 app hosting .net assemblies).

You want to run REGASM /unregister *.dll.  The *.tlb is a product of running REGASM /TLB.

If you have your .net project is registered for COM interop, it should do this for you at ever build.

Comment: thats what i was doing, the way i resolved it was deleting every .dll everywhere, rebuilding it, and rerunning the batch file, and that solved my problem. However that is not a good long term solution

Comment: you only need to register once (this places an entry in regedit under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib) unless you move the file, like after a merge into another branch.  It sounds like you have VB open while rebuilding .NET. That would be a problem.  Close VB first.